# How to fill in matrix with values from another matrix with repeat columns and rows in R

Tags: r, matrix

This is an *extension* to the great question and answer found here:
[How to populate matrix with values from another matrix in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075302/how-to-populate-matrix-with-values-from-another-matrix-in-r)

**The problem**

Similar to the referred chain - I want to populate a matrix based off another matrix. The difference is that, in my instance, the new matrix has repeated column and row names.

**Example**

Take this empty matrix. (N.B. That some of the columns and rows have the same name):

```
> m1 <- matrix(ncol=9, nrow=9)
> rownames(m1) <- c('a','b','b','c','d','c','f','e','f')
> colnames(m1) <- c('a','b','b','c','d','c','f','e','f')
> m1

  a  b  b  c  d  c  f  e  f
a NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
d NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
e NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I want to use the infomation in this distance matrix (m2) and add the correct values into m1.

```
df <- data.frame(pop = c('a','b','c','d', 'e','f'), fake_coords = seq(1:6))
head(df)

m2 <- as.matrix(dist(df$fake_coords, diag = T))
rownames(m2) <- df$pop
colnames(m2) <- df$pop
m2

 a b c d e f
a 0 1 2 3 4 5
b 1 0 1 2 3 4
c 2 1 0 1 2 3
d 3 2 1 0 1 2
e 4 3 2 1 0 1
f 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

The previous chain suggests this as a solution:

```
cols <- colnames(m1)[colnames(m1) %in% colnames(m2)]
rows <- rownames(m1)[rownames(m1) %in% rownames(m2)]

m1[rows, cols] <- m2[rows, cols]
m1

  a  b  b  c  d  c  f  e  f
a  0  1 NA  2  3 NA  5  4 NA
b  1  0 NA  1  2 NA  4  3 NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c  2  1 NA  0  1 NA  3  2 NA
d  3  2 NA  1  0 NA  2  1 NA
c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
f  5  4 NA  3  2 NA  0  1 NA
e  4  3 NA  2  1 NA  1  0 NA
f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

However as you can see it works, but only for the first instance of the column or row name.

**Question**

Is there a way to make this work across all matching rows and columns in a matrix, not just the first instance?

*Side note:*
The order of my columns and rows do matter - these are the population that individuals are from. They will be linked (and hence need to be in the same order) to another datafile.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

**EDIT**

This suggested link and method [How to replace values from a matrix with another matrix based on column/row names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810823/how-to-replace-values-from-a-matrix-with-another-matrix-based-on-column-row-name) produces the same problem.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the link and your help. I have just tried this method but unfortunately it outputs the same result. i.e. Only matches the first instance of the column or row

Comment: `m2[rownames(m1), colnames(m1)]`

Comment: Oh my goodness! @Roland - you are a genius - How simple and it works! I have been getting so confused with this, thank you so much. Not sure why it works, but so glad it does. :D I am not sure how to mark this as the answer for you as it is a comment?

Comment: It's just a frame change: You don't fill a matrix (you rarely do that in R), you subset a matrix.